# Deserialize XML without a property

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I have the following XML, but I'm not able to deserialize to the object I need.

```
<response>
          <texts>
                 <text name="blabla">This is bla</text>
                 <text name="test xpto">This is a text</text>
           (…)
           </texts>
</response>
```

This is what I've tried so far:

```
public class ResponseTexts : Response
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "texts")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "text"]
    public List<Text> Texts { get; set; }
}

public class Text
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "text")]
    public string TextValue { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But so far the TextValue always come as null....can someone enlight me?

thanks in advance

Comment: What about `Text.Name`?

Comment: Text.Name comes with the correct value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use XmlText to get element value. Here is correct serialziation attributes:

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "texts")]
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "text")]
    public List<Text> Texts { get; set; }
}

public class Text
{
    [XmlText]
    public string TextValue { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
using(var stream = File.OpenRead(path_to_xml))
{
   var response = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Result:

```
{
  Texts: [
    { TextValue: "This is bla", Name: "blabla" },
    { TextValue: "This is a text", Name: "test xpto" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In `visual studio 2013`:
Copy your XML in buffer (just select it and press `CTRL+C`) go to `Edit` -> `Paste Special` -> `Paste XML as Classes`

Comment: You're answer helped me to get to the solution, but the @Sergey answer is more what I was looking for! Thanks!